# Disadvantages of using parent() and children() methods in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, children

I use the parent() and children() methods a lot in JQuery. Typically I do things like this:

```
<div id="somediv">
    <ul>
        <li id="listitem">item one</li>
        <li id="listitem">item two</li>
        <li id="listitem">item three</li>
        <li id="listitem">item four</li>
    </ul>

    <ol>
        <li id="anotherlist">
            <button id="addItem">additem</button>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

$("#addItem").click(function(){
    var num = $(this).parent().parent().parent().children().children("#listitem").size();
    alert(num);
});
```

The main issue I really want to address is that if the layout of a web page changes then obviously the number of calls made to each of those methods needs to change as well. I don't particularly feel that using them the way I have is necessarily the best way of solving the problem.

Basically when you click the button it just displays the number of items in the first list. (Sorry for not stating earlier).

Comment: `ID` must be unique use `class` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use closest and find. Currently you have four elements with same id i.e. `listitem` You should use unique ids. You can use common `class` instead

```
var num = $(this).closest('#somediv').find("#listitem").size();
```

Using common class and unique ids.

**HTML**

```
<div id="somediv">
    <ul>
        <li id="listitem1" class="someclass">item one</li>
        <li id="listitem2" class="someclass">item two</li>
        <li id="listitem3" class="someclass">item three</li>
        <li id="listitem4" class="someclass">item four</li>
    </ul>

    <ol>
        <li id="anotherlist">
            <button id="addItem">additem</button>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var num = $(this).closest('#somediv').find(".someclass").size();
```

Comment: yes that is a much better way. Much shorter and more reliable. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of serieses `parent` calls, use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest). Instead of serieses of `children` calls, use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find). That way, there are much more significant changes you can make to your HTML structure without impacting your code.

So for instance *(note I've changed `listitem` to a class, see below for why; also, `size()` was deprecated years ago, use `length`)*:

```
$("#addItem").click(function(){
    var num = $(this).closest("#somediv").find(".listitem").length;
    alert(num);
});
```

Of course, you don't need `closest` in that example because `#somediv` is an ID selector, but if it were a class selector, or something else structural...

---

As Tushar Gupta points out, your HTML is invalid. You can't use the same `id` value on multiple elements, `id` values **must** be unique. (Hence the word "identifier.")

In your case, you probably wanted to use `class`.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, just trying to get things done fast. Sloppy is no good either.

Comment: Closest and Find are a much better choice, if you ever go back and change your html, the .parent and .children will break.